# Can we run Robotframework test cases through Maven Surefire Plugin to run them parallel

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, maven

Hi I have created some test cases in Robot framework and now I wat to run them in parallel. I know there is Pabot to run test suites in parallel but my requirement is to run them through Maven Surefire Plugin where we can set up the threads to be created.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only tool that allows you to run in parallel something written in robot framework is [pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot).

Things you should know:

1. Pabot will split test execution from suite files and not from
   individual test level.
2. The order of tests execution in each suite file is sequential and
   you can't randomize

The only way to parallelize each test is to use one test per suite file and then use Pabot. But this is bad practice because you will have to cut the suite setup and there will be some code duplication. Maybe there is a possibility to use init file to define folder level setup, but this is also bad practice because you'll cut the autocompletion if you define resources in init file.

So if you don't like Pabot you have to create your own test runner which in my mind is a huge task to do.

Answer (score 0):

It must be possible. Here is a sample config for parllel execution using maven sure fire plugin:

```
    <plugin>   
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>   
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>   
    <version>2.5</version>   
    <configuration>     
    <parallel>methods</parallel>     
    <threadCount>4</threadCount>   
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Head over to [link for more details](https://dzone.com/articles/running-junit-tests-parallel).